# How to delete adjacent rows with the same values in R?

Tags: r

I have a huge data frame (log) that looks like this:

```
wordTar1    wordTar2
1   vital   vital
2   vital   raccoon
3   raccoon vital
4   vital   cerebrum
5   cerebrum    accumulates
6   accumulates accumulates
7   accumulates cerebrum
8   cerebrum    cerebrum
9   cerebrum    cerebrum
```

What I need to do is to get rid of the adjacent (horizontal) rows with repetitive words. Basically, this is what I need:

```
wordTar1    wordTar2
1   vital   raccoon
2   raccoon vital
3   vital   cerebrum
4   cerebrum    accumulates
5   accumulates cerebrum
```

Comment: `df = subset(df, df$wordTar1 != df$wordTar2)`

Comment: or with `dplyr` : `filter(dat, wordTar1 != wordTar2)` or `dat %>% filter(wordTar1 != wordTar2)`

Answer (score 1):

If the data frame is called `data`, then the following should work:

`data[data[,"wordTar1"]!=data[,"wordTar2"],]`

If the character in the first column does not match the character in the second column, then `TRUE` and the row is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df1[df1$wordTar1!=df1$wordTar2,]
```

Comment: hmmm... I used the other ones but I would try this one as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can use something like

`data <- data[data$wordTar1 != data$wordTar2,]`

Then to find all of the unique rows, use `unique`, as in:

`data <- unique(data)`